# How to parse Eddystone UID BLE beacon info

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am try to write a parser for BLE Eddystone UID packet, but don't know how exactly to do it.
I am using Beacon Simulator App to broadcast a Eddystone UID Packet, and when I tested with different mobile using same app as scanner I can see that Eddystone UID packet broadcasted by 1st Device.

I want to write a sample app to scan for Eddystone UID packets.
I know I have to use `BluetoothLeScanner` and in `onScanResult` of `ScanCallback` I can get all the Bluetooth devices compatible with BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy).

But the problem is I am able to extract device mac, device name from `ScanResult` and can validate that I am able to hear my bluetooth headset and speaker but I am not sure how exactly I will get `namespace` and `instance` of the Eddystone UID and I am not able to see any such variable in `ScanResult` which will help me.

Can anyone please point me to any snippet or any code regarding how to do it. I don't want to use any third party library for scanning, simple plain in Kotlin or in java.
Kotlin is preferred but java is also fine, I am aware of both language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Eddystone UID**: A unique, static ID with a 10-byte Namespace component and a 6-byte Instance component.
In `onScanResult` you can extract Eddystone uid packet like below

```
override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
            val scanRecord = result.scanRecord
            if (scanRecord != null) {
                val serviceUuids = scanRecord.serviceUuids
                if (serviceUuids != null && serviceUuids.size > 0 && serviceUuids.contains(
                        eddystoneServiceId
                    )
                ) {
                    val serviceData = scanRecord.getServiceData(eddystoneServiceId)
                    if (serviceData != null && serviceData.size > 18) {
                        val eddystoneUUID =
                            Utils.toHexString(Arrays.copyOfRange(serviceData, 2, 18))
                        val namespace = String(eddystoneUUID.toCharArray().sliceArray(0..19))
                        val instance = String(
                            eddystoneUUID.toCharArray()
                                .sliceArray(20 until eddystoneUUID.toCharArray().size)
                        )

                        Log.e("DINKAR", "Namespace:$namespace Instance:$instance")
                    }
                }
               
            }
        }
```

**scanRecord**: a combination of advertisement and scan response

**serviceUuids**: list of service UUIDs within the advertisement that are used to identify the Bluetooth GATT services.

**eddystoneServiceId** : Service UUID for Eddystone UID which is “0000FEAA-0000–1000–8000–00805F9B34FB”

**serviceData**: the service data byte array associated with the serviceUuid, in our case eddystoneServiceId

eddystoneUID packet info is there in serviceData from index 2 to 18, we need to convert this byte array to Hex string using the utility method.

**namespace** is of 10 bytes which are starting 20 characters of eddystoneUID

**instanceId** is of 6 bytes which are the remaining 12 characters of eddystoneUID

sample to show you how you can convert your byte array to Hex String

```
   private val HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray()
fun toHexString(bytes: ByteArray): String {
    if (bytes.isEmpty()) {
        return ""
    }
    val hexChars = CharArray(bytes.size * 2)
    for (j in bytes.indices) {
        val v = (bytes[j].toInt() and 0xFF)
        hexChars[j * 2] = HEX[v ushr 4]
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX[v and 0x0F]
    }
    return String(hexChars)
}
```

I have written a blog on the parsing of Eddystone UID and iBeacon as well you can refer to it [here](https://www.talentica.com/blogs/scanning-ibeacon-and-eddystone-using-android-ble-scanner/)

Also, you can refer to the complete working sample app to scan for Eddystone UID, iBeacon and normal Bluetooth peripherals [here](https://github.com/dk19121991/BLEScanner)

Comment: tried your sample app and its working like butter smooth, thanks a lot dude.
Can I use use your whole code from your repo and tweak as per my need or there is some license stuff involved ?

Comment: glad that I could have been any help to you.

Comment: no license it's completely fine you can use all the code from my repo.

Comment: If I was any help to you can you please accept this answer and upvote as well, it helps.

Comment: Sure, why not, Let me do that for you.